# How to highlight items on Desktop using xfce?

Tags: xfce

Im using xfce but the text of the symbols on my desktop are not underlined by a colour, which means I can rarely see them (Black on dark-blue).
-> like home and trash

How to enable the background of the text?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consult this link: [Hidden Options](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfdesktop/advanced) and look at the section reproduced below:

```
The colors of the icon text and the icon text background, as well as the
opacity of the icon text background, can be customized by putting directives
similar to the following in your ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file:


style "xfdesktop-icon-view" {

    XfdesktopIconView::label-alpha = 75
    base[NORMAL] = "#00ff00"
    base[SELECTED] = "#5050ff"
    base[ACTIVE] = "#0000ff"

    fg[NORMAL] = "#ff0000"
    fg[SELECTED] = "#ff0000"
    fg[ACTIVE] = "#ff0000"
}
widget_class "*XfdesktopIconView*" style "xfdesktop-icon-view"


The first entry sets the opacity of the rounded text background. The three 
“base” entries set the text background color, and the three “fg” entries 
set the text color.

The “NORMAL” entries set the color for the regular, unselected state. The 
“SELECTED” entries set the color for when the icon is selected, and the
desktop has keyboard focus. The “ACTIVE” entries set the color for when 
the icon is selected, but the desktop does not have keyboard focus.
```

(If you don't have a hidden **text** file called .gtkrc-2.0 in your home folder, create it with a text editor and put what is recommended above in there. Obviously, you will have to choose colors of background and text that are compatible with your wallpaper, if any. Most operating systems come with a color chooser. I use gcolor2 from the Ubuntu Software Center.)

---

Recent versions of Greybird, which I think is the default theme in Xubuntu, now have a section in `/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` which can be tweaked instead of `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. Just search for  `style "xfdesktop-icon-view"`. (Greybird is included in `shimmer-themes`.)